# Is it possible to prevent a chat room from appearing in the sidebar of a site?

Tags: support, chat, sidebar, specific-site

I'm currently writing new aviation-related commands for the chat bot, and I've setup [a room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12308/aviation-chat-bot-testing) to debug in.

Is it possible to remove this room from the sidebar?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? If you want to restrict other people from talking in the room, you can set it to *Gallery* mode.

Comment: @Stijn he doesn't want it to bump out the main room due to testing

Comment: @Stijn I don't mind people coming in and chatting... but as Manishearth said, I spam the room with a lot of commands to the bot (the stats show almost 1,000 messages in the room in 3 days, and I reckon at least 50% of them are commands).